# Tomcat connection pool not releasing idle connections

Tags: tomcat7, connection-pooling

I am using tomcat DBCP on tomcat 7.0.42 with Oracle database. Following is an example of my resource definition:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/DB_alias1"
   auth="Container"
   type="javax.sql.DataSource"
   fairQueue="true"
   username="user"
   password="password"
   driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
   url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(...)"
   timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="180000"
   minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="120000"
   maxActive="50"
   maxIdle="4"
   minIdle="4"
   maxWait="10000"
   initialSize="4"
   initSQL="<A valid init SQL>"
   validationQuery="SELECT 1 from dual"
   validationInterval="60000"
   testOnBorrow="false"
   testOnReturn="false"
   testWhileIdle="true"
   removeAbandonedTimeout="120"
   removeAbandoned="true"
   logAbandoned="false"
/>
```

On startup 4 initial connections are created. Based on the above configuration, after `minEvictableIdleTimeMillis`, all idle connections should be eligible for being recycled/destroyed.

Since I have 4 minIdle connections, I expect these 4 connections to recycled/destroyed every `timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis` seconds and 4 new connections to be created with a fresh logon time. On checking connections in database, I see that the logon time remains the same from when initial connections were created and these never update even after a day or two. These stale connections are providing incorrect results in case there has been any change in data from DB.

This was not the case with Apache commons DBCP where connections were recycled automatically based on the `timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis`.

I tried searching this forum for hints on a solution but nothing has worked so far. I was wondering if I may not have the configurations done right. Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Since I have 4 minIdle connections, I expect these 4 connections to recycled/destroyed every timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis seconds

No. Quite the opposite. minIdle = 4 says that you allow four connections to remain in the pool even when they are idle (in fact, the pool will even grow to maintain four idle connections if necessary).

> These stale connections are providing incorrect results in case there has been any change in data from DB.

That should never happen, no matter when the connection was created.

A connection will issue a fresh query, even if the connection was created days ago. Unless you have some very weird caching in place.

What could happen with idle connections is that they time-out and get disconnected. But that should be taken care of by the validationQuery.

Comment: Stale results usually indicates a failure to commit a transaction.

Comment: @Thilo: Thank you for your comment. With minIdle, I understand that at least 4 connections would be kept idle at all times but does this mean that the minEvictableIdleTimeMillis will not be honored anymore? I assume these idle connections should be done away with at timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis and new 4 connections come up (yes they will be idle). Isn't that the case?

Comment: @Thilo and Mark: For the second part concerning stale results. 
There are no transactions to commit. This is a reporting app based off an OLAP implementation and are attaching the analytic workspaces as part of init sql query. The init sql as we know fires once when new connections are created in pool.

This helps us to "warm up" our connections and avoid cube attach times at query execution. Since idle connections are never released after minEvictableIdleTimeMillis, data provided is from an older generation.

Comment: My question would be, how can I make sure that the there are always 4 idle "warmed up" connections available at all times and once past the minEvictableIdleTimeMillis time then they are recycled after every timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis.

Comment: "I assume these idle connections should be done away with at timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis". No. The idle connector will just close idle connections to get down to minIdle. It won't close a connection just to reopen another one. I don't think there is a parameter to do that. And you should not need one, really. The validationQuery can check if the connection is still alive. If it is, it is good to use. You need to find out what is causing this "stale data". It is probably something else.

Comment: "You need to find out what is causing this "stale data". Re-read the comment about initSQL. Can you maybe re-run parts of that logic in the validationQuery to attach the connection to the right data? If not, you may have to patch the connection pool or handle this in application code somehow. Sounds like you actually want to switch connections every X hours even when they are not idle. Can you maybe just restart the application server every X hours?